# How to center a RatingBar in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, ratingbar

I have created a custom RatingBar as described in one of the tutorials given here on stack-overflow and it's looking great, the problem is with the centering of the image. here is what I've got:
[image]

As you can see the TextView is centered vertically in the LinearLayout, but the RatingBar is at the top of it. Here is my xml code of this image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            style="@style/starsRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="2.3"
            android:stepSize="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the code of the styling:

```
<style name="starsRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_ratingbar_full</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">36dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">36dip</item>
    </style>
```

Any ideas in the RatingBar would be apprisiated!

THANKS

Comment: Have you tried `center_vertical`?

Comment: yes, it didn't helped

Comment: I think you also need to set `layout_height` to `match_parent`, so that it has the full height to work the gravity in ...

Comment: still nothing, maybe something in the custom styling of the starsRatingBar

Comment: I would remove the `Height` statements in the starsRatingBar xml, change the `layout_height` to `match_parent` and see what that does.

Comment: still nothing... very strange

Comment: Have you tried using `android:gravity` rather than `android:layout_gravity`?

Comment: Is it possible that the white underneath the stars is part of the ratings bar?

Comment: I don't know, there is nothing in the layout. How can I check this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30014/discussion-between-neil-townsend-and-vlad-ioffe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it.

The key issue is the `ScrollView`: it automatically makes things compact, unless you specifically tell it otherwise. In the scroll view, set

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to make it use the space available.

Answer (score 0):

Hello to get all items at top you have to put:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text="TextView" />
```

instead of:

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
```

if you just want the rating bar centred:
just remove style="@style/starsRatingBar"

**EDIT:**
forget any think I said befor, it seems to work better when I changed the style to : (adjust your min/max height to get "perfect result" )

```
<style name="starsRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/star_on</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">26dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">26dip</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: but `style="@style/starsRatingBar"` is my RatingBar custom styling. The question was: how to center vertically the RatingBar.

Comment: can you please post your style "starsRatingBar"