# layout_weight does not work when the layout inside a ScrollView is larger than the ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-scrollview

I'm trying to use a linear layout's layout_weight for the height inside of a scrollview. However I find that layout_weight would only work with fillViewPort=true and if there is enough remaining space for the linear_weight to expand.

I have listed three examples below and I want to make textView the same size in #2 and #3 as #1 in xml level.
As you can see in the link, in #2, #3, textView was automatically changed.

Here are my examples. The TextViews and Buttons are enclosed inside of a LinearLayout and then inside of a scrollView.

## 1. Layout_weight working perfectly relative to the parent. (Working)

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/v0gl2tmyp/Screen_Shot_2013_06_26_at_4_30_51_PM.png]

## 2. Layout_weight working relative to the remaining space and not the parent.(Not Working)

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/sx65v5n5t/Screen_Shot_2013_06_26_at_4_30_44_PM.png]

## 3 Layout_weight ignored (Not Working)

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/ibmaj5gu9/Screen_Shot_2013_06_26_at_4_40_32_PM.png]

Here's my xml code for #3. #2 and #1 is basically the same code with less or no buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weighSum="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="Accept" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="#AAABBB"
            android:text="hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#BBBAAA"

            android:text="hello" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="#AAABBB"

            android:text="hello" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: (Working Case) http://s22.postimg.org/v0gl2tmyp/Screen_Shot_2013_06_26_at_4_30_51_PM.png

Comment: Can you add the xml for these three scenarios?  It would help make it more clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Or do you want entire layout done by someone else?

Comment: Hi, I just want to get the layout_weight working. But I think layout_weight does not work due to the nature of the scrollView where it manipulates its child's height. So I just want to see if I'm wrong and there is a work around for the scenario #2 and #3. Thanks.

Comment: i think the workaround that you are looking for is to set the minHeight attribute on your "weighted" views. see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weights are working as they were designed. Maybe not the way you want them to "work", but saying they are "not working" is inaccurate. Think about your 3rd case for a second, what size in pixels would you expect the TextViews to be?  Weights are a percentage of the available space (not total size of the parent).  The scrollview and linearlayout are, at a minimum, the size of your screen, otherwise the sum of all the children views. So if your children views exceed the size of the screen (the ones without weights), how much space do you expect to be allocated for the remaining views (the ones with 0dp and weights)?  The point is that amount of space is arbitrary, android will not try to assume how much space you want, because it has no possible way of knowing.

TL;DR - set a minHeight (in dp) on your textviews to handle the case where you have too many buttons.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I looked at the source code for the linear layout and it only works with **remaining space** and any layout that exceeds  the space will be set to wrap_content. Thank you for the reply. I wish that there is a better way to manipulate the child layout in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

The images are exactly what I would expect to see for your xml.

This may help you:

1. When the system is layout putting the `View`s on the screen using the weight approach, it allocates only the *spare* space according to the weight, not the *total* space. Therefore, to make it allocate the total space be allocated according to the weights (which is what most people intuitively expect), you have to set the dimension you want it to work in to 0dip. So, for those `Button`s and `TextView`s you need to set

   ```
   android:layout_height = "0dip"
   ```
2. You may also need to force the `ScrollView` to fill the viewport to stop everything scrunching up. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568310/how-to-center-a-ratingbar-in-android/16585566#16585566)

   ```
   android:fillViewport="true"
   ```
3. A personal observation. Sometimes weights seem to work in inverse (ie smaller weights give more space). YMMV.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I put buttons in there to make the layout inside larger and no other reason. I'm only interested in making the textViews proportion to the parent layout. Also, I edited the code, I accidentally pasted wrong code but in either way, case #3 does not work.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The picture you show for layout 3 is exactly what I would expect the xml to give. What were you expecting?

Comment: I wanted the textViews to grow with respect to the weight and its parent. So textView #1 will grow 60%,  textView #2 will grow 30%, textView #3 will grow 50% in height.

Comment: So, have your tried setting the `layout_height` of the `TextView`s and the `Button`s to `"0dip"` as I've suggested?

Comment: Yes, I have and it doesn't work. That method will work as long as I have my LinearLayout not bigger than the scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting layout_height="0dp" on the elements that have layout_weight.  The enclosing layout object will use any free space to grow them as much as it can.

Also your use of weightSum is a bit questionable.  Normally weightSum should be >= the total weights of the enclosed views.  You have one weightSum where none of the directly enclosed views have weight and another where the total weight of the enclosed views exceeds weightSum.   This second case will lead to strange behavior.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. My sum weights of the views are larger than the weighsum is because to test to see if it can make the virtual dimension in the ScrollView larger. However, it turns out the layout_weight can only uses **remaining space available**. So the exceeding bound will be just cropped.