# Android layout_weight for overflowing linear layout height

Tags: android, android-layout

My scenario is like this:
I have a linear layout in which I have one Image view and about 10 editTexts. I want the ImageView to be half of the size of the screen height and remaining edit texts to occupy rest of the space and scroll if required.

I wrapped my linear layout inside a scroll view and assigned the weight sum of 10 to the linear layout. Then assigned layout_weight of 5 to the imageView and rest of all were left with layout_height of wrap_content. But this hides the imageview totally. How should I get the kind of layout I want?

**My layout.xml:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#bcddff"
                />
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Launch Camera"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Name"
                android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Mobile No."
                android:id="@+id/mobile" android:layout_gravity="center" android:inputType="phone"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Whatsapp No."
                android:id="@+id/whatsapp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:inputType="phone"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Age"
                android:id="@+id/age" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:id="@+id/address" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="City"
                android:id="@+id/city" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="State"
                android:id="@+id/state" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Gender(M/F)"
                android:id="@+id/gender" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Remarks"
                android:id="@+id/remarks" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330216/layout-weight-does-not-work-when-the-layout-inside-a-scrollview-is-larger-than-t

Answer (score 0):

When Setting Layout weight either the height must be match_parent or 0dp(If Match_parent the layout get bigger as the weight is reduced, and ironically if 0dp, the layout gets bigger as the weight increases). Layout weight does not work accurately when the parent is in wrap_content.

Hope this helps,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#bcddff" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Launch Camera" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Name" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Mobile No."
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/whatsapp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Whatsapp No."
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Age" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Address" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="City" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/state"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="State" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Gender(M/F)" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remarks"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Remarks" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```